# What killed Aerea Targaryen?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The *Fire & Blood* chapter "Jaehaerys and Alysanne, Their Triumphs and Tragedies" details the striking death of Aerea Targaryen in 56 AC, though there is a great deal of mystery surrounding this event. Aerea returns from an unknown location, "Balerion had wounds as well", and Grand Maester Benifer who was said to record everything he witnessed is silent on this event. All that we have is an account from Septon Barth.

> The things... Mother have mercy, I do not know how to speak of them... they were... worms with faces... snakes with hands... twisting, slimy, unspeakable things that seemed to writhe and pulse and squirm as they came bursting from her flesh. Some were no bigger than my little finger, but one at least was as long as my arm... oh, Warrior protect me, the *sounds* they made...
>
> -Septon Barth, *Fire & Blood*

What was this creature that killed Aerea Targaryen?

Comment: I doubt that it's an existing mythological creature. It could be (there are a lot of weird and creepy myths out there), but I see no reason to believe that Martin didn't just invent it.

Comment: Some variety of abominations from ruins of Valyria. It seems these parts have sort of mutagenic influence.

Comment: It's possible the wounds on Balerion were inflicted by a large wyrm (I don't remember it being said that they went extinct with the Doom), as I can't think of even any mutated creature that would be large enough or powerful enough to do that.